# Как добавить новый ключ с элементом на 0 индекс в словаре?

Tags: python, python-3.x, dict

У меня есть словарь:

```
pp = {'title': 'jr', 'description': '64', 'price': '3'}
```

Я хотел бы добавить в него ключ на 0 индекс, чтобы все остальные ключи только сдвинулись, вывод должен быть:

```
{'key:': '#789', 'title': 'jr', 'description': '64', 'price': '3'}
```

В качестве ключа рассматриваю `'key'` cо значением `'#789'`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

У элементов словаря не существует индекса. Да и гарантированное сохранение порядка ключей словаря появилось только в Python 3.7 (в версии Python 3.6 это зависело от реализации).

Таким образом решить данную задачу можно только пересоздав словарь с правильным порядком ключей:

```
res = {**{'key:': '#789'}, **pp}
```

результат:

```
In [193]: res
Out[193]: {'key:': '#789', 'title': 'jr', 'description': '64', 'price': '3'}
```

---

PS для Python 3.9+ можно попробовать использовать [новый оператор](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0584/):

```
res = {'key:': '#789'} | pp
```

Comment: а что если теперь необходимо добавить другой ключ, но уже на первый индекс? :)

Comment: @MaximChyorny, алгоритм тот же ) Вы можете перезаписывать результат в переменную. `pp`, как это показано в ответе nomnoms12

Comment: уточняющий вопрос, как я понял в python 3.8 такое работать не будет?

Comment: @MaximChyorny, если вы об этом варианте - `{'key:': '#789'} | pp` - нет не будет. Это будет работать начиная с Python 3.9.0

Answer (score 4):

TL;DR:

```py
pp = {'key': '#789', **pp}
```

---

Порядок ключей в словаре не имеет значения, поэтому стандартного способа сделать это нет. Вам придётся пересоздать словарь.

До версии 3.6 (CPython) порядок ключей вообще не сохранялся. В версиях выше это поведение добавили из-за новой реализации словарей, при которой хеш-таблица хранится отдельно от данных, что позволяет непосредственно итерировать данные:

```py
indices =  [None, 1, None, None, None, 0, None, 2]
entries =  [[-9092791511155847987, 'timmy', 'red'],
            [-8522787127447073495, 'barry', 'green'],
            [-6480567542315338377, 'guido', 'blue']]
```

Подробнее о новой реализации словарей можно прочитать в статье 
[Немного внутренностей словарей в CPython (и PyPy)](https://habr.com/ru/post/432996/).

Answer (score 3):

А ещё есть `OrderedDict`, гарантирующий порядок ключей в более ранних версиях питона:

```
from collections import OrderedDict

a = OrderedDict({'title': 'jr', 'description': '64', 'price': '3'})
a.update({'key': '#789'})
a.move_to_end('key', last=False)
print(a)
print(dict(a))
```

Вывод:

```
OrderedDict([('key', '#789'), ('title', 'jr'), ('description', '64'), ('price', '3')])
{'key': '#789', 'title': 'jr', 'description': '64', 'price': '3'}
```

Comment: большущее вам спасибо, что оставили свой ответ, для более ранних версий python!